# Pearson Coefficient of Skewness

Tags: statistics

There are two formulas for Pearson coefficient of skewness: 3(mean-mode)/(standard) deviation and (mean-median)/(standard deviation). When I employ both of this methods to find Pearson coefficient method, I get different answers, why? Is it still correct, if so, why?

Comment: You are using incorrect definition. Exchange mode by mean in your formulas. Check this link http://www.statisticshowto.com/pearsons-coefficient-of-skewness/